# Open a "Save As" / "Download" dialog with JavaScript to download a file created on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I have a NGINX+Flask+KnockoutJS single page app and I want to create a download button that allow the user to download the data he/she is visualising and manipulating client side **without reloading the full page**
There are a number of pure JavaScript solutions (like [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html)) but none of them is fully compatible with all major browsers (e.g. Safari).

Basically what I would like to have is:

1. The app shows a table to the user
2. The user push the download button
3. JavaScript sends data to a server side endpoint
4. The server generate the file on the fly based on the data sent from the client
5. The browser open the download/save as dialog

Is it possible?

Comment: download.js author here: if anyone knows a safari fix, i'd be very grateful. that said, if you generate the content with a server, you can simply use a content-disposition header to trigger a download in a hidden iframe.

Comment: there's a good snip up top that will show you how to download a form response, or iframe location change:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-examples

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible?

Of course. Let's have an example:

> 1. The app shows a table to the user

You mean, something along the lines of using a `<table>` tag:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo bar</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>
            <form action="/download/foo/bar/123" method="post">
                <button type="submit" value="Download foo bar 123" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>

    ... here come some other rows of the table ...
</table>
```

> 2. The user push the download button

OK, this one is obvious. The user submits the form by clicking on the corresponding submit button on the desired row of your table.

> 3. JavaScript sends data to a server side endpoint

Why care about javascript when you have standard HTML forms which can submit data to the server in a purely browser agnostic manner, like shown in point 1.? And if you really cared about some javascript you could always subscribe to the `onsubmit` action of the `<form>` I showed earlier and inject the necessary data as hidden fields into the DOM using javascript.

> 4. The server generate the file on the fly based on the data sent from the client

Yeah, that's like standard HTTP protocol. The server will simply handle the `/download/foo/bar/123` endpoint and simply send the file as attachment:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 29
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foobar123.bin

HERE COMES THE BINARY CONTENT
```

> 5. The browser open the download/save as dialog

That's exactly what any browser's gonna do when it handles the previously shown HTTP response from a server.

Conclusion: The HTTP protocol and standard HTML forms already provide you with the necessary tools to achieve your requirements. And if you wanted a little bit of additional fanciness, just enhance the HTML form upon submission using javascript in order to append any required fields as hidden input elements that you would like to send to the server. And then leave it to the browser to handle the download.

Comment: Thank you, I do care about JavaScript because I want do download the file without a page refresh (I edited my question to clarify) I tried to send a POST HTTP request to my server app endpoint but even if the HTTP response is successful the file is not downloaded.

Comment: There's no page refresh if the user POSTs an HTML form to a server side endpoint which streams a file with a `Content-Disposition`: attachment header as shown in my answer. A `Save As` dialog is simply shown for the user to select the file destination and no page reload occurs whatsoever.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it! I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will display the Save As dialog box according to its own download settings. Whether or not the file gets downloaded depends on whether the OS has a program to handle opening the file. You can force the download (override opening the file) by making an anchor with the download attribute.

Comment: safari doesn't support `a[download]`, as per OP... http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Doesn't really change the fact of my answer, which is the the browser dictates what to do with downloaded files, not any JS code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are right, but the point is not the dialog per se. I just used this to explain the fact that I want the file to be downloaded and not opened in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In the and I realised that maybe my questions was not 100% clear. Anyway I want to share the solution I come up with. I created two end poin in my Flask app:

The first get the data from the client via AJAX POST and store them temporary in Redis (I had already a Redis instance active for caching) and generate a UUID for the file.

```
@mod.route("/create-csv", methods=['POST'])
def create_csv():
    csv_string = request.form.get('csv')
    file_id = str(uuid())
    rstore.setex(file_id, 60, csv_string)
    return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('api.download',
                                              file_id=file_id,
                                              _external=True, 
                                              _scheme='https')}
```

The second endpoint just send the file to the client with the appropriate headers.

```
@mod.route("/download/<file_id>", methods=['GET'])
def download(file_id):
    file_content = rstore.get(file_id)
    response = make_response(file_content)
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=keywords.csv"
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/octet-stream"
    return response
```

On the client site I have the following JavaScript code:

```
  self.save = function(csvdata) {
    $.post( "/api/create-csv", csvdata, function(data, status, response){

      var file_url = response.getResponseHeader('Location');
      window.location.assign(file_url);

    });
  }
```

So when the POST request is successfully sent I just assign to the current URL the URL for the file download.

Answer (score 0):

SaveAs-Dialog only in **https** can be open via *(window as any).showSaveFilePicker(pickerOptions)*:

```
async saveAs(data: string) {
    const filename = 'conf1.conf';
    if ('showSaveFilePicker' in window) {
        const pickerOptions = {
            suggestedName: filename,
            types: [
                {
                    description: 'Text File',
                    accept: {
                        'text/plain': ['.conf'],
                    },
                },
            ],
        };

        const fileHandle = await (window as any).showSaveFilePicker(pickerOptions);
        if (fileHandle) {
            const writableFileStream = await fileHandle.createWritable();
            if (writableFileStream) {
                var taBlob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
                await writableFileStream.write(taBlob);
                await writableFileStream.close();
                // this.messageService.add({ severity: 'info', summary: 'Saved ok', detail: '' });
            }
        }
    } // else { // no https
}
```